Why active is not set correctly in <x-nav-link component?
On laravel / livewire site I have defined route in routes/web.php :
Route::get('/', HomePage::Class)->name('home');

But I failed to set active link with code :
<x-nav-link :href="route('home')" :active="request()->is('home')" wire:navigate >Home</x-nav-link>

OR
<x-nav-link href="{{ route('home') }}" :active="request()->is('home')" wire:navigate >Home</x-nav-link>

I suppose that 2 operators are equal.
But link is always inactive, as I set in resources/views/components/nav-link.blade.php:
@props(['active'])

@php
$classes = ($active ?? false)
? 'inline-flex items-center px-1 pt-1 border-b-2 border-indigo-400 text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:border-indigo-700 transition duration-150 ease-in-out d1'
: 'inline-flex items-center px-1 pt-1 border-b-2 border-transparent text-sm font-medium leading-5 text-gray-500 hover:text-gray-700 hover:border-gray-300 focus:outline-none focus:text-gray-700 focus:border-gray-300 transition duration-150 ease-in-out';
@endphp

::{{$active }};;
<a {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => $classes]) }}>
    {{ $slot }}
</a>

Line :
::{{$active }};;

always shows empty value.
"laravel/framework": "^11.10.0",
"livewire/livewire": "^3.5",
Thanks in advance!

The problem is that you are using incorrect Request method.
Instead of
request()->is('home')

you should rather use:
request()->routeIs('home')

See https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/requests#inspecting-the-request-path for details
